# Unity Dynamic Serializable Field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to set a dynamic serializable field within unity? I have tried using `object` and `UnityEngine.Object`, both give errors.

`object` doesn't seem to be serializable, because `value` is null.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

`UnityEngine.Object` is serializable, but when I try to set an int to it I get the following error:

> type is not a supported int value

So what is a way that I can set a dynamic type to the variable?

```
public enum ValueType { Integer, Float, String, Boolean, GameObject }

public class SetVariable : ScriptableObject {
  public ValueType valueType;
  public string key;
  public object value;
}
```

I then have a custom inspector script that looks like this:

```
SerializedObject serializedObject;

public void SetObject(MyObject obj) {
  serializedObject = new SerializedObject(obj);
}

public override void OnDisplay() {
  accessType = serializedObject.FindProperty("accessType");
  key = serializedObject.FindProperty("key");
  value = serializedObject.FindProperty("value");
}

public override void OnGUI() {
  EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(valueType);
  EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(key);

  if (key.stringValue.Trim().Length > 0) {
    switch (valueType.enumNames[valueType.enumValueIndex]) {
      case "Integer":
        value.intValue = EditorGUILayout.IntField(value.displayName, value.intValue);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you've included enough code here. What is `serializedObject`?

Comment: @Draco18s I updated the question with some more code, also: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject-ctor.html

Comment: Where is `SetObject` called from? Why are you using a boxed type like this?

Comment: You/Unity can't. But you can write your own type that at least could cover the types you need.  [See here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/serializing-an-array-of-mixed-serializable-types.532152/)